# How to get rid of async in function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, nightwatch.js

Let's say I have this code:

```
const myFunction = async => {
  const result = await foobar()
}

const foobar = async () => {
  const result = {}
  result.foo = await foo()
  result.bar = await bar()
  return result
}
```

And I want this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  const result = foobar()
}
```

I tried to wrap **foobar** like this:

```
const foobar = async () => {
  return (async () => {
    const result = {}
    result.foo = await foo()
    result.bar = await bar()
    return result
  })()
}
```

But this still return a promise

I can't use **.then** in **myFunction**, I need that **foobar** returns the result variable instead a promise.

The problem is that **myFunction** is an async function and it will return a promise but It should return undefine I need to get rid of async in **myFunction**.

Edit: as Sebastian Speitel said, I want to convert **myFunction** to sync

Edit 2: to Shilly, I am using nightwatch for end2end test, nightwatch will call **myFunction()** if there are no errors in the execution of the function it will run perfectly, if there's an error then nightwatch's virtual machines will run forever instead stop, this problem happens if the called function is async.

Comment: To make async function sync again you either need to use a callback or a while(true) to prevent code execution until the promise resolves

Comment: What do you mean by getting rid of async? Do you want your code to stop all execution until `foo()` and `bar()` are finished? What is inside the `foo()` and `bar()` functions? Can you rewrite those to not return Promises?

Comment: To rewrite your function in a sync mode you should make sync the functions _foo()_ and _bar()_. If those functions are an external API, you should check if there is a sync version. Be aware that if you rewrite in a sync mode it will be sensible slower.

Comment: Can you explain more of the context of Why this has to be removed? Since what you're asking is rather peculiar, usually people want it the other way around, so it might be an x/y question. We'll need to know what foobar() does to know if it can be turned into a callback.

Comment: @Shilly edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using .executeAsync() and then having the promise call the .done() callback? That way it should be possible to wrap foobar and just keep either the async or any .then() calls inside that wrapper.

My nightwatch knowledge is very stale, but maybe something like:

```
() => {
  client.executeAsync(( data, done ) => {
    const result = await foobar();
    done( result );
  });
};
```

or:

```
  () => {
    client.executeAsync(( data, done ) => foobar().then( result => done( result )));
  };
```

Comment: If it doesn't work with .executeAsync function change to .perform function, just changed .executeAsync for .perform and it works.

Answer (score 2):

To change an asynchronous function into a normal synchronous function you simply have to drop the `async` keyword and as a result all `await` keywords within that function.

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    const result = await foobar();
    // ...
    return 'value';
};

// becomes

const myFunction = () => {
    const result = foobar();
    // ...
    return 'value';
};
```

You should however keep one simple rule in mind.

1. You can't change a asynchronous function into a synchronous function if the return value depends on the value(s) of the resolved promise(s).

This means that functions that handle promises inside their body, but from whom the return value doesn't depend on those resolved promises are perfectly fine as synchronous functions. In most other scenarios you can't drop the asynchronous behaviour.

The following code gives you an example for your situation, assuming the return value of *myFunction* doesn't depend on the resolved promise.

```
const myFunction = () => {
    const result = foobar();

    result.then(data => doSomethingElse(data))
          .catch(error => console.error(error));

    return 'some value not dependent on the promise result';
};
```

If you want to learn more about promises I suggest checking out the [promises guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and the [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) page.

Answer (score 0):

Any function marked with `async` will return a Promise. This:

```
const foobar = async () => {
  return 7;
}
```

Will a return a Promise of 7. This is completely independent of wether the function that calls `foobar` is `async` or not, or uses `await` or not when calling it.

So, you're problem is not (only) with `myFunction`: is `foobar` using `async` which forces it to always return a Promise.

Now, said that, **you probably can't achieve what you want**. Async-Await **is only syntax sugar for promises**. What you're trying is to [return a synchronous value from an asynchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), and this is basically forbidden in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing very important understanding here between the synchronous and asynchronous nature of the code.

Not every async function can be converted to synchronous function. You can use callback pattern instead of await/async, but I doubt that would be useful to you.

Instead I would recommend you just use `await`, as in your first code example, and leave functions as async, it shouldn't harm your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
    function foo(){
      return 'foo'
    }
    function bar(){
      return 'bar'
    }
    const foobar = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
          let result = {}
          result.foo = foo()
          result.bar = bar()
          return resolve(result)
        })
    }

    const myFunction = () => {
      const result = foobar()
      let response = {}
      result.then(val=>{
        response = Object.assign({}, val);
        return response
      });
    }

    var test = myFunction()
    console.log(test)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that *myFunction* doesn't have a return value and will therefore return `undefined`.

Comment: does foo and bar return promise or they return normal values